# npm install adds command files and bash files

Tags: node.js, git, npm, node-modules

I run `npm install` in my base folder and get the following:
[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

--Update--

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependecies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-declare": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-handlebars": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-insert": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.4.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.6.5",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "gulp-wrap": "^0.13.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.10",
    "jasmine": "^2.7.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.7.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint": "^4.14.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.2",
    "gulp-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.3",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-trx-reporter": "^0.2.9",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "author": ""
}
```

I have removed my node and git, then reinstalled both.
My node version is 8.9.4
My npm version is 5.6.0
My git version is 2.15.1.windows.2
I am on Windows 10

My main confusion is why this has worked and stopped. Also it works without issue on my colleagues machines with the same settings.

Comment: May be u are missing .`gitignore` file or i think these files are not included in `.gitignore`. check it once.

Comment: I have run `npm install` for a while now and these have started appearing. I cannot believe that they should be added to folder holding package.json.

Comment: Post code block - **not** image

Comment: Seems odd- can you post some of your `package.json` code. And if your project structure is unusual, then post that as well. Also give details on your system, e.g. which version of npm, version of node, version of git, OS, and anything else relevant...

Comment: @Lissy Added as much as I could. I added the image as that is not code, that is the behavior that is off. `npm install` is adding files to the package.json file on my machine, not my colleagues. With the same settings.

Comment: Are you concerned about the files appearing, or them being visible in git?

Comment: @LightBender Both really. The real issue is it seems to be something that is messing with my node installation. Files are copied over, but if I, for example, try to global install gulp (`npm install -g gulp`) gulp is not added to the path.

This means, concretely, that I no longer can use my machine to develop front-end code.